# #Error On Calculated Field

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I am new to Microsoft Report Builder and so can somebody help me.

I have search the Internet but cannot find an answer to my problem.

How can I replace the #Error with "-" from the following calculation when the Date of Birth field is blank.

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Year,Fields!Date_of_Birth,Fields!Date.Value
```

I am using Report Builder 2.00.

Answer (score 0):

Use an If statement to check if the Date of Birth field is blank and return "-" if it is, otherwise run your code normally:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Date_of_Birth.Value), "-", DateDiff(DateInterval.Year,Fields!Date_of_Birth.Value,Fields!Date.Value))
```